# Two screens merging even with exact attribute - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I'm trying to create a website with React router dom but the problem is two of my routes are merging for some reason even with exact tag. admin screen is not merging with detail screen but detail screen is merging with admin screen(detail screen also appears when I go into admin panel but admin screen do not appear in detail screen). My code is like this:

```
<Router>
<Route path='/:productID' exact component={DetailScreen} />
<Route path='/admin' exact component={AdminPanel} />
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"admin" is, in the router's eyes, a valid product ID.

Wrap the two routes in a [`<Switch>`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) to only allow one to render, then flip them the other way around so admin is first (so it's matched over the "catch-all").